# Why is Google Sheets IMPORTRANGE not working?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I tried to use this formula:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11GoENoRd_niJjJUa-tBxDKuORVzxPLGPMl4HdzbSUPo/edit#gid=1393359549", "Выкупы!A1:A1")
```

But I got this error:

[image: error_img]

Can someone help me?

Comment: It is difficult (or impossible) to tell people with certainty what is going on with a sheet when we don't have access to that sheet. It's rather like calling a mechanic and saying, "My car isn't working. I can't bring it in for you to look at it, but what's wrong with it and how do I fix it?" The most efficient way to receive help on a specific problem like this is to share a link to the sheet, being sure to set the link's Share permission (when you create the link) to "Anyone with the link..." and "Editor."

Comment: My above comment notwithstanding, it's possible that your "gid" reference is competing with the individual sheet name you're requesting. You only need the ID of a spreadsheet as the first parameter for IMPORTRANGE; and "A1:A1" is redundant.. So you can try this: `=IMPORTRANGE("11GoENoRd_niJjJUa-tBxDKuORVzxPLGPMl4HdzbSUPo","Выкупы!A1")`

Comment: You can create own two sheets and repeat my command

Comment: This forum and all others like it are 100% attended by people who choose to volunteer their time and expertise to help people—not by employees who are paid to do so. To ask volunteers to spend extra time on your request by making our own sheets to help you solve your problem, at no cost to you, is not reasonable nor is the goal of this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can open this website for solution your problem : [link](https://blog.coupler.io/importrange-not-working/)

Comment: Thank you for link, bu I can not find how to import only one column

Comment: can you hover to loading? waht the error massage

Comment: Error
Cannot find range or sheet for imported range. =importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11GoENoRd_niJjJUa-tBxDKuORVzxPLGPMl4HdzbSUPo/edit#gid=1393359549","Trello Board!A:")

Comment: I tried to load only column A to another sheet

Comment: Without seeing the files, I'm not sure what the problem is.  Usually the problem occurs because the name of the tab/sheet does not match what is in the formula. (ie You don't use the name of the file in the formula, you use the name of the individual tab/sheet.)

Comment: The tabs names are the same. =importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11GoENoRd_niJjJUa-tBxDKuORVzxPLGPMl4HdzbSUPo/edit#gid=1393359549","test!A:C")

This not worling too, where test is name  and range A:C

Comment: Can be a problem that I work in the same document but in diffferent sheets?

Answer (score 0):

I found one solution after trying for days. its simple like this.
Go to share the portion of the google sheets file which will be imported into or is not being properly imported. There you would remove the share links to existing emails and share to the public option to restricted and then redo the share.(This is almost like resetting the share option). Doing this my problem went away
[PUBLIC OPTION TO SHARE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9sUw5.png)